# Is it possible find files using SVN comments

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

JIRA has integration with SVN and CVS, where user can find files names/changes based upon the comments we put while committing.

Similar way, can we do it from Eclipse SVN plugin/tortoise client or some other tool?

e.g.
 I am committing a.java,b.java, c.java with comment [Issue-121] security threats issue.
I should able to find file names using comments "[Issue-121] security threats issue" .

Answer (score 2):

In TortoiseSVN: `right click > Show log`. In upper left corner you have a text field saying *"Filter by messages, authors, paths, revisions, bug-ids, date, date range"*.

Type in part of your commit message and it will show you all revisions that has such commit message. Clicking on revision will show the list of affected files.